# How to improve this sql query performance？

Tags: mysql

`SELECT id, name, detail FROM student WHERE id NOT IN (1,788,103,100) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000,10`

The table is tiny (10,000 rows). I have to consider two point, "IN query" and "LIMIT query".

Here are the DDLs and the EXPLAIN. I'm using MySQL 5.6.4.

```
CREATE TABLE student 
( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
, name varchar(45) NOT NULL
, detail varchar(255) NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | student| ALL  | Primary,id    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 13   |       |
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN`to find out where you need an index.

Comment: when i use `EXPLAIN` , the `IN` query use primary key and the ``NOT IN`` use nothing, does it weird?

Comment: close to 10,000 rows

Comment: How is it possible that rows = 13 !?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

The LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses mean that the query has to build the whole table and then order it and then go the record 1000 and then extract the next 10 records.

Why are you looking for 10 records starting at record 1000?

Removing the ORDER BY clause would make it faster as the query would only need to extract 1010 records.

Comment: I can't see a way - it is what it is.  Check the version of mysql - NOT IN performance is much higher in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this finding...

```
SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.16    |
+-----------+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;
  +----------+
  | COUNT(*) |
  +----------+
  |   131072 |
  +----------+

SELECT id
  FROM student
 WHERE id
   NOT IN (1,788,103,100)
 ORDER
    BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1000,10;
  +--------+
  | id     |
  +--------+
  | 195591 |
  | 195590 |
  | 195589 |
  | 195588 |
  | 195587 |
  | 195586 |
  | 195585 |
  | 195584 |
  | 195583 |
  | 195582 |
  +--------+
  10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | student | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 131069 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: id is a primary key .Sorry, I can not get your point ,do you mean that the query is fast enough in this ‘huge’ data？It's obsolute tity .23333

Comment: <!-- language: lang-sql -->
CREATE TABLE student (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  detail varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY name_unique (name),
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

Comment: The UNIQUE KEY on `id` is redundant - but I doubt that it makes any difference. Also, where's `review_name`?

Comment: +—-+————-+——-+——+—————+——+———+——+——+——-+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+—-+————-+——-+——+—————+——+———+——+——+——-+
| 1 | SIMPLE | student| ALL | Primary,id | NULL | NULL | NULL | 13 | |
+—-+————-+——-+——+—————+——+———+——+——+——-+

Comment: I think the UNIQUE id is confusing MySQL somehow. Get rid of it and try again.

Comment: i find someone said if i use ``NOT IN``, mysql won't use index but `` IN`` use

Comment: Clearly, as my EXPLAIN proves, someone is mistaken